# xUnit and test output in VSTS (to logs)

Tags: c#, testing, azure-devops, xunit

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 library and xUnit test project for it. The test runs fine locally (Debug and Release, it has different settings) and then it doesn't work when published to VSTS. So I need some king of tracing/logging when it runs there. What to use with xUnit to be able to see test output in the VSTS logs?

The test looks like this:

```
public class BlobHelperShould : TestBase
{
    public BlobHelperShould(ITestOutputHelper output) : base(output)
    {
        LoggerFactoryFixture loggerFactoryFixture = new LoggerFactoryFixture();
        // ... skip
    }

    // ... and then the tests go here

}
```

So I have `ITestOutputHelper` available. But if I use `WriteLine` I don't get anything in VSTS logs.

Comment: You can download the trx of the test running in the test results

Comment: ok, but how do I add up logs?

Comment: you cannot, https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3986

Comment: Which task you used to run test? Can you share a sample project on the OneDrive. Based on the test with a Xunit test project, the Console.WriteLine log shows in VSTS logs.

Comment: I use .NET Core Test task 1.*.   Console??? Why Console?

Comment: With Console.WriteLine method, the content can be show in VSTS log. Do you try it?